# How can you override default browser HTML5 video controls?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to change the custom shortcuts of a video player to those of Youtube. On Youtube the arrow keys rewind and fast forward 5 seconds each.  By default on Firefox and Google, when the left arrow key is pressed the video is rewound by 15 seconds, when the right arrow key is pressed the video is fast forwarded by 15 seconds. I'd like to get it to be 5 seconds.  I've tried using e.preventDefault() to no avail. I have the same issue with the space bar.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Current Code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        event.preventDefault();
        video.currentTime -= 5;
} else if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
        event.preventDefault();
        video.currentTime += 5;
        }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623808/2813224) it works perfect in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what is provided in OP code it looks like it should work. The only way it wouldn't is that `video` is null. `event.key` should probably be `event.code`. Of course that `event.preventDefault()` doesn't help nor hinder...or it helps in the fact if the arrow keys default behavior interfered somehow...can't really see how in your situation though.

---

#### Demo

```js
window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

function vidCtrl(e) {
  const vid = document.querySelector('video');
  const key = e.code;

  if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    vid.currentTime -= 5;
    if (vid.currentTime < 0) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
    vid.currentTime += 5;
    if (vid.currentTime > vid.duration) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'Space') {
    if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
video {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<video src='https://glsec.s3.amazonaws.com/mp4/60s.mp4'></video>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I was having issues with Chrome inconsistently adding time but your code works in incognito mode (maybe some sort of extension conflict) and is much cleaner than mine. Thanks!

Comment: Incognito mode? Yes, it must be a strange extension conflict. We'll I'm glad to help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if controls on your video element are disabled in your HTML document.

```
<video *controls* width="250">  Remove *controls*
```

if that is disabled, and still not working for you, you could try using JQuery to solve the problem by using:

```
<video id="video" type="video/mp4" src="./video.mp4" autoplay></video>

var vid = document.getElementById("video");

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (video.paused) {
      playVideo();
    }else {
      pauseVideo();
    }
  }else if(e.which == 39){
    skipForward();
  }else if(e.which == 37){
    skipBackward();
  }
});

function skipForward() {
  vid.currentTime += 10.0;

  $("#skip_forward_visual").removeClass("v_hidden");  // Visual Indicator

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#skip_forward_visual").addClass("v_hidden");
  }, 400);
}

function skipBackward(){
  vid.currentTime -= 10.0;

  $("#skip_backward_visual").removeClass("v_hidden"); // Visual Indicator

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#skip_backward_visual").addClass("v_hidden");
  }, 400);
}
```

Comment: To remove controls off of `<audio>` or `<video>` is `document.querySelector('video').controls = false;` BTW the jQuery will not work. Why are you posting code you haven't even tested?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. That just hides the visible player controls (play button, pause button, scrubber, duration,) from the user but has no effect on the default keyboard shortcuts. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: I was correcting UnReal G because his code is very wrong. I haven't bothered to try to answer yet. I'll post now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just quickly posted. I've created my own player and here is my code. I'm sorry I am new to stack overflow answering so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.It will override left and right keys and seek video to given number.

```
<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video'); //video element
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
if (event.keyCode  === 37) { 
        //Left
        video.currentTime -= 10;
} else if (event.keyCode === 39) { 
        //Right
        video.currentTime += 10;
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. It just adds that amount on top of the default browser's HTML5 Video arrow shortcut's amount.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think zer00ne solution is not working as it is not overriding the default forward/backward time of youtube of 5 seconds (at least for me, be it with Firefox or Chrome). In fact, I think his solution simply adds 5 seconds to the 5 seconds by default.

I have tried to find a better solution but even with this code

```
window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

function vidCtrl(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const vid = document.querySelector('video');
  const timeCurrent = vid.currentTime
  console.log(timeCurrent);
}
```

the current time returned is the one after the default behavior of forward/backward of 5 seconds has happened. I do not really understand.

Edit: Looks like the problem is the same here: [JavaScript - Prevent default in html5 video tag while fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910656/javascript-prevent-default-in-html5-video-tag-while-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

I forward the video similar to the other examples (video.currentTime += 5;)
However, when the video player has focus it would jump by a different amount. It used to be 1 min and now is 7.5 seconds (using Chrome).

However, using a document.activeElement.blur(); would remove the focus from the video player and made it jump by 5 seconds again